# Get wp_current_user_id using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, database, forms

awesome people of the Stack Community!

Like the newbie coder I am, it took many hours but at last I got:

- a HTML form inside wordpress ->
- to submit value to MySQL database ->
- and then store the values inside the table.

This page and form requires a login to use, so what I'm trying to do now is getting the **wp_current_user_id** stored in a field in the table "order" and the field userID.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance for any kinds of help.
Cheers.

### **order_confirmation.php**

```
<?php

   $db_name = "dbname";
   $db_user = "username";
   $db_pass = "cool_password";
   $db_host = "hostname";

    include 'config.php';

    $db_conn = connectToDB($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    //Get values from the form then -> database
    $sql = mysqli_query($db_conn, "
        INSERT INTO ordre(
            user_fname,
            user_lname,
            user_address, 
            user_email,
            user_phone, 
            service_chosen,
            user_note,
            order_date,
            statusID
        )
        VALUES(
            '".$_POST['user_fname']."',
            '".$_POST['user_lname']."',
            '".$_POST['user_address']."',
            '".$_POST['user_email']."',
            '".$_POST['user_phone']."',
            '".$_POST['service_chosen']."',
            '".$_POST['user_note']."',
            '".date('Y-m-d')."',
            '1' 
        )
    ");

    if($sql == TRUE) {
        echo "<p>Yay it worked</p>"; 
        );

    } else {
        echo "<p>Error: " . mysqli_errno($sql) . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

### **config.php**

```
<?php

function connectToDB($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {

//Create the db connection
$db_conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

//Print out an error if any
if($db_conn->connect_error) {
    die('Error #' . $db_conn->connect_errno . ': ' . $db_conn->connect_error);
} 
else {
    //Connected msg
    echo "Connected: " . $db_conn->host_info;
}
    return $db_conn;
}
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't you let WordPress handle the DB stuff? like, `require('wp-blog-header.php')` which is in the root, then use `wp_get_current_user()->ID` to get the user ID if logged in.. Also look at `$wpdb` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb for handling db queries..

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a school project and our teacher have named some specific things we must do and this is one of them, create your own form, your own tables inside the database and get them in with your own mysqli queries. In his examples he also used this method, prob not the best but it is what it is :)

Comment: Ah. So now, getting `wp_current_user_id` stored in a table. Is it okay to use `$wpdb` this time?

Comment: I should imagine so since all the other values are "by the teachers book". But how to make it it work inside order_confirmation.php?

Comment: Okay. First off, require the WordPress loader file `require('wp-blog-header.php');` (make sure the path is correct). Then, add this to your file after modification `global $wpdb; $table = $wpdb->prefix . "table_name"; $query = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE fieldName = 'wp_current_user_id'"); print_r($query);` ..

Comment: That didn't quite work but you put me on right track, thank you so much dude :D

What I did was `require ('../wp-blog-header.php');

        global $wpdb;
        
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $skrivID = $current_user->ID;`

Then in the insert query I added userID on the top and used the variable under VALUES. I'll update the thread. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Samuel Elh I manage to get this done.

I added this to my order-confirmation.php after I included config.php

```
    require ('../wp-blog-header.php');

    global $wpdb;

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $skrivID = $current_user->ID;
```

Then the insert query, I added the table I wanted the user ID stored in and used the variable $skrivID as value.

```
        $sql = mysqli_query($db_conn, "
        INSERT INTO ordre(
            userID,
            user_fname,
            user_lname,
            user_address, 
            user_email,
            user_phone, 
            service_chosen,
            user_note,
            order_date,
            statusID
        )
        VALUES(
            '".$skrivID."',
            '".$_POST['user_fname']."',
            '".$_POST['user_lname']."',
            '".$_POST['user_address']."',
            '".$_POST['user_email']."',
            '".$_POST['user_phone']."',
            '".$_POST['service_chosen']."',
            '".$_POST['user_note']."',
            '".date('Y-m-d')."',
            '1' 
        )
    ");
```

Ran the form with two different users and voila

[image: http://dump.no/files/b007c7cd4c6e/2016-05-19_10_28_18-frigg.hiof.no___localhost___interaktiv_v1631___ordre___phpMyAdmin_2.9.1.1.jpg]

Thanks again Samuel!

Comment: Awesome! glad you got it working now. I'd suggest looking at https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/best-practices/security/validating-sanitizing-escaping/ while inserting data, to prevent possible SQL injections at least you could sanitize the user submitted data (e.g `sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_fname'] )`). Good luck with the rest of the project :)

Comment: @SamuelElh Thanks for the tip, I assume having good security will score some extra points ^^, Thanks man, appreciate your help. 

Now just to figure out this stuff: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227174/print-out-wordpress-user-id-two-sites-with-same-code-but-different-output
=D

Comment: No worries. You're welcome. You can mark your answer as accepted for future viewers :)

Comment: I will, must wait until tomorrow ^^,

Comment: Ah got it. I had the same experience when I first joined StackOverflow ;)