# Print out Wordpress user ID - two sites with same code but different output

Tags: php, wpdb

Trying my luck once more with more smarter and awesome peeps =D

In my last question the issue was regarding getting wordpress user ID, which worked perfectly after someone steered me in the right direction.

Now I'm trying to help my friend achieve this with the same code but she doesn't get the user id no matter what we try.

**The php code**

```
require ('../wp-blog-header.php'); 

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $printID = $current_user->ID;

    echo $printID;
```

This gives me the ID of the user who is logged in.

I tried using the same code on her site, she's got a subfolder but that should be fine right?

```
require ('../Wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); 

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $printID = $current_user->ID;

    echo $printID;
```

This prints out "0", doesn't matter which user that is logged in, still zero :(

Anyone got some tips? :D

Comment: Feels like the user is not logged in.. Can you try out `print_r( wp_get_current_user() )` or simply `var_dump( is_user_logged_in() _`? About the sub-folder, that should be the correct path since you didn't get any errors..

Comment: I tried `require ('../wp-blog-header.php');` with both of those strings but it just crashed with a 500 error :(

Comment: My bad: `print_r( wp_get_current_user() ); var_dump( is_user_logged_in() );` little syntax errors I made. Hope you're working on a local installation or you have control over your server.

Comment: Your on to something @SamuelElh =D
My output: `WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [user_login] => gruffmeister[user_fname]`
Her output: `WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( ) [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => )`

Your right, it doesn't see that I'm logged in. Cookie trouble because of the subdirectory or some login issues maybe? :S

Comment: Trouble lol. Not sure if cookies, if you use Chrome you can check them through the 'View site information' icon in the address bar. Is her site running on HTTPS?

Comment: Doesn't seem she's running HTTPS, but I think I've found the issue, it's ridonculous really xD. I have my WP install in the root of the server, and a folder there named functions where I get my php stuff. _Heeeer_ on the other hand have a subdir Wordpress, and instead of have a functions folder inside that folder, it was beside the Wordpress subdir in the root folder. **Tunnel vision** much XD. I moved the folder and fixed the requires and src over her page and now her output is `WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [user_login] => Gruffmeister [user_pass] =>`

Comment: Ahh yes so you are making calls to another installation where no session is set for you.. Yes ridiculous but awesome you figured it out lol. Guess you're resolved now. Good luck with the rest of the work :)

Comment: Yeah, it was major confused, poor server ^^, Guess I should take a break now. Thanks again @SamuelElh =D I'd be happy to follow any social media if your active somewhere and wants some followerzzz :D
Thanks man, cheers (Y)

Comment: It's okay you're welcome! I'd recommend to install WordPress on your computer locally to save you time and efforts instead of hitting the online server every time, unless you have to. Ohh if you need to contact me about anything I'd be happy to help Twitter@samuel_elh ;)

Comment: And if possible, try to make a short quick answer below describing it was a directory-related issue. Readers and moderators would appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was directory related.

The Wordpress installation was in

- htdocs/wordpress/

The functions folder with the PHP files was in

- htdocs/functions/

So when the scripts were called upon, even if the src url was correct it wouldn't run it, I'm not sure exactly what it searched for but after moving functions inside the wordpress directory and fixing the target and action links it worked instantly.

So the new directory were

- htdocs/wordpress/functions

Thanks to @SamuelElh once again for his support :)